# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow]

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am trying to deploy my first Spring webflow application. However, I am stuck for 3 days with following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow]

I have read number of articles and forums, but could not find any solution.

Following are the dependencies I am adding in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the classpath file showing the jar files in my classpath

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources" output="target/test-classes" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/webflow/spring-webflow/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/webflow/spring-binding/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-binding-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/webflow/spring-js/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-js-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/webflow/spring-js-resources/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-js-resources-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted this out. I was referring the flow xml instead of webflow configuration inside the mvc configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. For me the problem was in web.xml which was linked to the flow definition file, like this (which is incorrect):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/myFlow.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Should have been like this (which is correct):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I hope this help someone, I've inverted like 4 hours in this.